# My discrete GPU disables the integrated GPU

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, intel-graphics, device-manager, discrete-graphics

I've just got a used Lenovo Erazer X310. It has an Intel i5-4460 with integrated Intel HD 4600 GPU. On the motherboard there is a VGA port and a HDMI port. The computer also has a discrete GPU: A Nvidia Geforce 750 ti. The Nvidia-card has 2 DVI ports.
The thing is that the Nvidia-card seems to totally disable the integrated GPU. So I'm not able to get a signal from the HDMI or VGA port. Also the Intel GPU is not displayed in Windows Device manager, only the Nvidia-card. (I have to use the DVI port on the Nvidia-card to get any video output.)

If I remove the Nvidia-card I can use the HDMI or VGA port and the Intel GPU is shown in Windows Device manager.

I would like to use the HDMI port to connect to my monitor but I would also like to be able to use the Nvidia-card when I play games. Is it possible to achieve somehow?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? I believe you couldn't use video devices that used different drivers until Windows 10. There may also be hardware limitations.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior on any Windows workstation OS. The built-in GPU is automatically disabled if another one is installed and won't show up in Device Manager. Hope that helps.

Comment: This sounded really weird, but it looks like it's correct.  If you have an official link with supporting info, this can be an excellent Answer. 
 https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3h3hpl/windows_10_isnt_using_dedicated_gpu/

Comment: I don't think that is entirely true. See this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/ There they show you that you should be able to pick which GPU (integrated or discrete) to use for a specific application/game. This particular setting is a feature added in Windows 10 April 2018 update. I got the latest version (1809) running on my machine.